# How to link boost libraries properly in Linux

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I've been trying to go through Boost tutorials but I got stuck at linking the filesystem library.

I have Ubuntu 12.10. Installation wasn't that hard

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

This put all headers in /usr/local/include and compiled sources in /usr/lib/ 
[--headers] 
[--binaries]

I wrote this program [--program]. When I tried to compiled it

```
 g++ -g tut1.cpp -o tut1 -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

got this errors: [--errors].

After a little search on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

 I tried this:

```
g++ -g -I /usr/local/include/boost/ tut1.cpp -o tut1 -L /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

but didn't have luck. I had the same errors.

Since I cannot put more than 2 links in the post, here are all links
http://pastebin.com/DakVFn12

Comment: Try reversing the order of the libraries in your link command.

Comment: Avoid external links... they may get broken!

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer myself here:
http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppLinkErrorUndefinedReferenceToBoostFilesystemDetailGet_current_path_api.htm

Looks like binaries weren't in /usr/lib but in /usr/local/lib.

 So the correct command for compilation would be:

```
g++ -g tut1.cpp -o tut1 -L/usr/local/lib/ -lboost_filesystem
```

@Yuushi, that was 1 problem.

Comment: I doubt `apt-get install libboost-dev-all` put stuff in `/usr/local`.

Comment: I don't know where you got your package, but Ubuntu 12.10's [libboost-dev package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libboost-dev) just pulls in [libboost1.49-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libboost1.49-dev) which [puts everything in `/usr`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/libboost1.49-dev/filelist) (including [filesystem](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/libboost-filesystem1.49-dev/filelist) and [system](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/libboost-system1.49-dev/filelist))

Comment: its apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Comment: How to link everything from boost?

Answer (score 4):

The `-L` command should be the base path where the libraries are contained, not the path to a specific library. Try with `-L /usr/lib/` instead.

Comment: `find /usr/lib -name "*boost*"`